# compile the following opencv python source code

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, opencv3.0

The following link contains the source code to create some 3D effects in images using Opencv & python. But the problem is I can't summarize the fractional codes. I need whole source code so that I can run it. If someone can gather the whole code that would be great for me.

https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_pose/py_pose.html

> Our problem is, we want to draw our 3D coordinate axis (X, Y, Z axes)
>   on our chessboard’s first corner. X axis in blue color, Y axis in
>   green color and Z axis in red color. So in-effect, Z axis should feel
>   like it is perpendicular to our chessboard plane.
>
> First, let’s load the camera matrix and distortion coefficients from
>   the previous calibration result.
>
> ```
> import cv2
> import numpy as np
> import glob
>
> # Load previously saved data
> with np.load('B.npz') as X:
>     mtx, dist, _, _ = [X[i] for i in ('mtx','dist','rvecs','tvecs')]
> ```
>
> Now let’s create a function, draw which takes the corners in the
>   chessboard (obtained using cv2.findChessboardCorners()) and axis
>   points to draw a 3D axis.
>
> ```
> def draw(img, corners, imgpts):
>     corner = tuple(corners[0].ravel())
>     img = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[0].ravel()), (255,0,0), 5)
>     img = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[1].ravel()), (0,255,0), 5)
>     img = cv2.line(img, corner, tuple(imgpts[2].ravel()), (0,0,255), 5)
>     return img
> ```
>
> Then as in previous case, we create termination criteria, object
>   points (3D points of corners in chessboard) and axis points. Axis
>   points are points in 3D space for drawing the axis. We draw axis of
>   length 3 (units will be in terms of chess square size since we
>   calibrated based on that size). So our X axis is drawn from (0,0,0) to
>   (3,0,0), so for Y axis. For Z axis, it is drawn from (0,0,0) to
>   (0,0,-3). Negative denotes it is drawn towards the camera.
>
> ```
> criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
> objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
> objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)
>
> axis = np.float32([[3,0,0], [0,3,0], [0,0,-3]]).reshape(-1,3)
> ```
>
> Now, as usual, we load each image. Search for 7x6 grid. If found, we
>   refine it with subcorner pixels. Then to calculate the rotation and
>   translation, we use the function, cv2.solvePnPRansac(). Once we those
>   transformation matrices, we use them to project our axis points to the
>   image plane. In simple words, we find the points on image plane
>   corresponding to each of (3,0,0),(0,3,0),(0,0,3) in 3D space. Once we
>   get them, we draw lines from the first corner to each of these points
>   using our draw() function. Done !!!
>
> ```
> for fname in glob.glob('left*.jpg'):
>     img = cv2.imread(fname)
>     gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
>     ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7,6),None)
>
>     if ret == True:
>         corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
>
>         # Find the rotation and translation vectors.
>         rvecs, tvecs, inliers = cv2.solvePnPRansac(objp, corners2, mtx, dist)
>
>         # project 3D points to image plane
>         imgpts, jac = cv2.projectPoints(axis, rvecs, tvecs, mtx, dist)
>
>         img = draw(img,corners2,imgpts)
>         cv2.imshow('img',img)
>         k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff
>         if k == 's':
>             cv2.imwrite(fname[:6]+'.png', img)
>
> cv2.destroyAllWindows()
> ```
>
> See some results below. Notice that each axis is 3 squares long.:
>
> [image]
>
> ## Render a Cube
>
> If you want to draw a cube, modify the draw() function and axis points
>   as follows.
>
> Modified draw() function:
>
> ```
> def draw(img, corners, imgpts):
>     imgpts = np.int32(imgpts).reshape(-1,2)
>
> # draw ground floor in green
> img = cv2.drawContours(img, [imgpts[:4]],-1,(0,255,0),-3)
>
> # draw pillars in blue color
> for i,j in zip(range(4),range(4,8)):
>     img = cv2.line(img, tuple(imgpts[i]), tuple(imgpts[j]),(255),3)
>
> # draw top layer in red color
> img = cv2.drawContours(img, [imgpts[4:]],-1,(0,0,255),3)
>
> return img
> ```
>
> Modified axis points. They are the 8 corners of a cube in 3D space:
>
> axis = np.float32([[0,0,0], [0,3,0], [3,3,0], [3,0,0],
>                      [0,0,-3],[0,3,-3],[3,3,-3],[3,0,-3] ])
>
> And look at the result below:
>
> [image]
>
> If you are interested in graphics, augmented reality etc, you can use
>   OpenGL to render more complicated figures.

Comment: It appears you just copied a large section of the tutorial here. What exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly I did. I just posted an answer to show that what is the result I concat those parts. Now can you tell me if is there anything wrong?

Comment: It's not clear to me where the `B.npz` and `left*.jpg` files exist. Otherwise, again, what particular errors are you getting?

Comment: I don't know about B.npz but left*.jpg is the image on which the 3D processing is going on.